# Is it ok to use "finally" at the end of the sentence like this?

Tags: grammar, differences, adverbs, adverb-position

Is it OK to use **finally** at the end of the sentence like this?

> I am a teacher **finally**.

Or are the below ones only possible?

> I **finally** am a teacher.
>
> I am **finally** a teacher.

Most people told me that *only* the adverb **eventually** could be placed at the end of a sentence, but I am just curious if I can place **finally** at the end.

Comment: It depends on what you're asking about. Is this something said aloud, or written? I would avoid it written, but spoken, that would sound fine.

Comment: In that context it has a slightly different meaning.  Rather than "eventually" it means "at the root" or some such.

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8870/where-is-the-correct-place-to-place-adverbs-in-sentences

Comment: It's  perfectly fine.

Answer (score -2):

Words like finally are adverbs ending in "ly" and like adjectives, it's better form to avoid using them at the end of a sentence. Using them at the beginning is acceptable. For example: Finally, I am a teacher after years of training.

Comment: I think you may have answered too quickly.

Comment: Why do you feel I answered too quickly?

Comment: You should read my sentence more carefully. :^)

Comment: 'Using them at the beginning is acceptable.' uses an adjective at the end of a sentence.

Comment: I think you mean to say that using adverbs at the end of a sentence is usually bad form.